# Save webpage "image" to variable for later processing with selenium

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, geckodriver

My selenium script opens a webpage, then does really slow one-by-another processing of DOM elements with css selectors, does calculations and inserts values to database.

I can speedup whole process if I do this calculation stuff in different thread while main thread will open next page do all required actions on that page and wait for second thread to finish, then do again.

But when browser leaves page I don't have access to DOM elements anymore, cause page has changed. I was wondering is it possible to save that webpage to some variable for later processing in other thread so I can make some kind of processing pool and whole app will be separated to 2 threads (browser thread, and processing/insert_db thread).

It's makes no sense to make a pool of just INSERT queries cause INSERT is not slow - whole processing routine with iterating over page elements is slow

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a thread for each "test"... a test being spawn a browser, navigate to a page, scrape page, push data to db, and finally close browser. At that point, you should be able to easily spawn 6+ tests running on a simple computer and it will run 6x faster.

Comment: I know this is a really shtty solution, but it might come handy, until you find out the real answer .... Try to open another browser ... this way you will have them both separated and at a same time you can work with them as a threads ... Hopefully it helped atleast a bit :)

Comment: @StyleZ Thanks for the tip, I'm gonna start several selenium instances for multithreading but actually if I could do what I asked about it could be even more faster (x2 times)